# Remotely Write Registry Key to "enable remote device manager"

Tags: key, registry

So here's what I have so far:

$PCname = Read-Host "Please enter the PC Name"

Reg ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Settings\ -Name AllowRemoteRPC -Value "dword:00000001"
Pause

I need to be able to enter a different PC name to write the new key to, and remotely write the registry key. I've tried miserably a few times, I get the feeling I'm missing a few biddles of info to do this correctly.